# Android How to add buttons in a simple notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have read the developers documentation , Now I leaned how to add Buttons in a large Notification.

```
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_update_normal, "action",getPendingIntent());
```

But how to add buttons in a simple notification ? Like the control buttons in the music app.

[image]

I have googled it like half a day , someone please help me , Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

i think you could make a customer layout ,then use layoutinflater inflate the view ,at last ,you can add the inflated view into the notifiction, hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think it's a custom layout , custom layout in notification bar  is very hard to match system style .  Thanks